# How to get needed view of list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have to check t-test assumptions. The output should be the list of vectors (statistic,parameter,p-value).

Indeed I found the solution, but I failed with answer representation.

```
one_sample_t <- function(test_data, general_mean){
  b <- names(which(sapply(test_data, is.numeric)))
  a <- sapply(test_data[b], function(x) (t.test(x,mu = general_mean)))
  as.list(as.data.frame(a[1:3,]))
}

one_sample_t(iris[, 1:4], 4)
```

My answer looks like this
[My wrong answer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbVGv.png)

But the correct answer is the only this
[Correct data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC2fO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
one_sample_t <- function(test_data, general_mean){
  b <- names(which(sapply(test_data, is.numeric)))
  a <- lapply(test_data[b], function(x) c(t.test(x,mu=general_mean)$statistic,t.test(x,mu=general_mean)$parameter,t.test(x,mu=general_mean)$p.value))
  a
}
one_sample_t(iris[, 1:4], 4)
```